# Set All Newly Created Folders in a Document Library have unique Permissions

Tags: permissions, folder

One of my users asked if it is possible to set a document library so that all newly created folders do not inherit permissions from the parent library. Once the folder is created, you must break inheritance from the library and set the new unique permissions, but my user would like to have this automatically done on creation of the folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can do it in SharePoint Designer by creating the `SharePoint 2010 Workflow` (also available in SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online) that will run after the item is created, adding the `Impersonating Step` to it and using the `Replace List Item Permissions` Action. In the action you should define the new users that will be able to access the folder.

The workflow should look something like this (tested in SharePoint Online):

```
Impersonation Step
The contents of this step will run as the workflow author:
    If Current Item:Content Type equals Folder
        Replace Full Control of item in Current Item
```